# how to set two Languages (Hebrew and English) single view store in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-enterprise

I want to set two language (Hebrew and English) in Magento single store view. By Default set language its a Hebrew.

i am using magento 1.9.0 and using magento porto theme.

please help me..

Comment: Refer this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19350/how-to-setup-multiple-language-in-magento-single-store-view